# Parameter 0 of constructor in .... Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am a fish in Spring Boot and Data Jpa, I Tried to create a basic Spring boot application but every time I am encountering the error. Can you help me?

That's my code:
Spring Boot Application class:

```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.*")
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.repository.*")
   @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.project.entities.*")
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   public class MainApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
 }
```

Controller Class:

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/api")
 public class controller {

private IUserServices userServices;

@Autowired
public controller(IUserServices userServices) {
    this.userServices = userServices;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/merhaba")
public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello World";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/getall")
public List<User> getAll(){
    return this.userServices.getAllUsers();
}
```

}

Repository Class:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

IServices Class:

```
@Service
public interface IUserServices {
void saveUser(User user);
List<User> getAllUsers();
```

}

ServicesImpl Class:

```
@Service
public class UserServicesImpl implements  IUserServices{

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public UserServicesImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
public void saveUser(User user) {
    this.userRepository.save(user);
}

@Override
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;

public User() {
}
public User(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
   }
}
```

AND THIS MY ERROR MESSAGE:

```
***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.project.services.UserServicesImpl required a bean of 
type 'com.project.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


   Action:

  Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.repository.UserRepository' in your 
  configuration.


  Process finished with exit code 0
```

SO This is application properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/u
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode = none
```

Comment: The package is not `foo.bar.*`, it is `foo.bar`, but as described below, just don't specify any of the extra annotations at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues that you should fix them.

### **First**

When you have the spring boot application with **@SpringBootApplication** you don't need other stuff such as `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and etc, So remove them all.
You can read more about it [**here**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

### **Second**

You don't need to annotate your service interface with @Service, because you did it in the `UserServicesImpl` class.

### **Third**

You defined `id` as an integer in your user entity but in the repository, you wrote your id as `Long`. It's wrong. It should be something like this.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
}
```

Try the above solutions and let me know the result.

Comment: Heyyy! When I removed the annotations in main class the program worked, Thank you so much <3